# Handle NullObjects across two models web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nullable

I have two models in my asp.net web api. One is the database model, and the other is the model the end user passes in and we map the properties like this:

```
public static IndividualProc ToIndividualnternal(this AssignmentExternal item) {
            return new IndividualProc() {
                IndividualID = (int)item.person.id, 
                EventID = (int)item.event.id,
                EventScehduleID = item.schedule.id,
                EventGroupID = item.group.id
            };
}
```

The problem is that when the user passes a null, I get an exception; "Nullable object must have a value".  How can I cast the nullable properties so that this exception is not caused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's nullable?  For the purpose of this answer I'm going to assume this is a nullable int:

```
item.event.id
```

and this is a regular int:

```
EventID
```

In that case, clearly you can't directly cast the former to the latter because there's no way for `int` to handle the case of a `null` value.  The `Nullable<t>` structure has properties to help check for that value:

```
EventID = item.event.id.HasValue ? item.event.id.Value : default(int)
```

This will check if the nullable int has a value and, if it does, use that value.  If it doesn't, use the default value for `int` (which is `0`).

Comment: OK, this really helps, thank you for the explanation as I was really confused before but I understand it now.